# max aggregation on grouped spark dataframe returns wrong value

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark dataframe containing 2 columns(`CPID` and `PluginDuration`). I need to find maximum `pluginDuration` and average `pluginDuration` for each `CPID` in the dataframe.

Rows returned for a `CPID` `AN04773` dataframe returned below rows:

```py
df.filter('CPID = "AN04773"').show(10)

Result: 
+-------+--------------+
|   CPID|PluginDuration|
+-------+--------------+
|AN04773|   1.933333333|
|AN04773|   13.03444444|
|AN04773|        9.2875|
|AN04773|   20.50027778|
+-------+--------------+
```

when I did `groupBy` on `PID` column of the dataframe to find `max` and `avg` plugin duration as below, I found the max value returned for some PIDs is not as expected. For example, for `PID` `AN04773` (same `PID` which I used to show rows from original df). The max `pluginDuration` should be `20.50027778` but from the result from the below code, the max value is `9.2875` which is not right.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
fdf = df.groupBy('CPID').agg(F.max('PluginDuration').alias('max_duration'),F.avg('PluginDuration').alias('avg_duration'))
fdf.filter('CPID = "AN04773"').show()

Result:
+-------+------------+--------------+
|   CPID|max_duration|  avg_duration|
+-------+------------+--------------+
|AN04773|      9.2875|11.18888888825|
+-------+------------+--------------+
```

want to know why it's not functioning as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wrong calculation happens because `PluginDuration` is not defined as a numeric datatype but as a string column. All you have to do is to cast `PluginDuration` column to be of a numeric type (double, float, etc).

Here is your issue (reproduced in `scala` but works the same in `PySpark`):

```
val data = Seq(("AN04773", "1.933333333"), ("AN04773", "13.03444444"), ("AN04773", "9.2875"), ("AN04773", "20.50027778")).toDF("id", "value")

data.groupBy("id").agg(functions.max("value"), avg("value")).show

// output:
+-------+----------+--------------+
|     id|max(value)|    avg(value)|
+-------+----------+--------------+
|AN04773|    9.2875|11.18888888825|
+-------+----------+--------------+
```

but after casting the `value` column to `Double` datatype, we get correct calculation values:

```
data.withColumn("value",col("value").cast("double")).groupBy("id").agg(functions.max("value"), avg("value")).show

// output:
+-------+-----------+--------------+
|     id| max(value)|    avg(value)|
+-------+-----------+--------------+
|AN04773|20.50027778|11.18888888825|
+-------+-----------+--------------+
```

Comment: can you please give the statement on how to write the output to a csv file? I've tries with "val law =  data.withColumn("value",col("value").cast("double")).groupBy("id").agg(functions.max("value"), avg("value")).show"  "law.write.csv("c1.csv")"------This throws the error as value write is not a member of unit...why is that??@Gabip

Comment: when you define the `law` dataframe, remove the `.show()` -- `show()` just prints the dataframe and returns nothing so the dataframe is not assigned as you expect.

Comment: It should be: `val law = data.withColumn("value",col("value").cast("double")).groupBy("id").agg(functions.max("value"), avg("value"))`

Answer (score 0):

As there is no datatype defined in the columns so Scala treated it as string and as a string 9 is greater than 2 , so the maximum is 9.285

Note: If you convert the datatype in pyspark to string you will get the same result as you are getting in Scala.

Answer (score 0):

```
def transform(self, df):

    from pyspark.sql.functions import sum, avg, max
    from pyspark.sql.functions import col
    
    #cast PluginDuration column from string to double to perform aggregation
    df1=df.withColumn('PluginDuration',
                      col('PluginDuration').cast('double'))

    df2=df1.groupBy("CPID") \
        .agg(max("PluginDuration").alias("max_duration"),avg("PluginDuration").alias("avg_duration"))

    

    #df2.show(truncate=False)
    #rename and round the column values
    df3 = df2.select(col("CPID").alias("chargepoint_id"),
                    func.round(df2["max_duration"], 2).alias("max_duration"),
                    func.round(df2["avg_duration"], 2).alias("avg_duration"))

    #df3.show(truncate=False)
 
    return df3
```