# PySpark max value for multiple columns

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, max, aggregate, multiple-columns

I have the below table:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('a', 1, 11, 44),
     ('b', 2, 21, 33),
     ('a', 2, 10, 40),
     ('c', 5, 55, 45),
     ('b', 4, 22, 35),
     ('a', 3,  9, 45)],
    ['id', 'left', 'right', 'centre'])
```

[image]

I need to find and display only the max values as shown below:

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

[![[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8bGq.png][2]][2]

Comment: you can do multiple aggregations within `agg()`. see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69795649/8279585)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple `groupBy` and `agg`:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = df.groupBy('id').agg(
    F.max('left').alias('max_left'),
    F.max('right').alias('max_right'),
    F.max('centre').alias('max_centre'),
)
df.show()
# +---+--------+---------+----------+
# | id|max_left|max_right|max_centre|
# +---+--------+---------+----------+
# |  b|       4|       22|        35|
# |  a|       3|       11|        45|
# |  c|       5|       55|        45|
# +---+--------+---------+----------+
```

Or slightly more advanced:

```py
df = df.groupBy('id').agg(
    *[F.max(c).alias(f'max_{c}') for c in df.columns if c != 'id']
)
```